# How to run configuration with hosting Angular WebStorm

Tags: angular-cli, webstorm

I wanted to know if it was possible to run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` instead of just `ng serve` just by modifying the confuguration in WebStorm? And if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either create/modify the npm script in `package.json` accordingly, like

```
"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"
```

and then use the existing run configuration/icon in the gutter to run this script, or specify the parameters right in your **NPM** run configuration, **Arguments:** field, using `-- --<option name>` format (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script#description), like `-- --host 0.0.0.0`:

[image]